# Append text onto html text input while typing

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to use jquery to append text onto what the user has typed in a text box, while the user is typing.

Say I wanted to append " is a hat" to the end of what the user typed.

Lets say the user starts typing "My Friend" into the field.

As they type the box will read:

```
M -> M is a hat
y -> My is a hat
  -> My  is a hat
F -> My F is a hat
r -> My Fr is a hat
...
```

I started writing a function for the keypress event, but then I realized that I would end up with something like

```
M -> M is a hat
y -> M is a haty is a hat
...
```

So what I want to know is how I should

1. Replace the old suffix
2. Place the cursor back to where the user was typing
3. Make sure they only are able to type before the suffix, so they they can't edit the suffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append to a `span` like so:

```
var phrase = " is a hat";
$("#idOfInput").keydown(function() {
    $("#idOfSpan").html(this.value + phrase);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

**JS**

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $(".dynamic").html(this.value);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
<div>
    <span class="dynamic"></span>
    <span class="static"> is a hat </span>
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxTb/)**

You will basically targeting the span that holds the dynamic text and render the html based on the keyup event.

Comment: I took tyme's just because of the difference of how he did it, but +1 for the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
this following example work perfectly .  
 **html**

    <input type="text" id="text"/>
    <p><span id="app"></span>
    <span>this is a hat</span>
    <p>

    **script**
    ----------
    $("#text").keyup(function(){
        $("#app").text($("input").val());
    });
```